# kernel symbol enabled but doesn't shows up in .config

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I added a flag (CONFIG_FLAG=y) in versatile_defconfig

This flag is defined in Kconfig somewhere in drivers directory

after updating the .config as follows

```
make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig
```

I cannot find the above flag in .config

and when I search CONFIG_FLAG in menuconfig as follows

```
make ARCH=arm menuconfig
```

I see the FLAG=n

What could be the possible reason, please help..also let me know if you need any other information.

I even tried adding it directly in .config, still it shows as disabled in menuconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to go into the Kconfig and enable it there by default..it works but I don't know how good this solution is.